# Retry POST request after authentication process

Tags: spring-mvc, authentication, post, spring-security, authorization

Let's assume the following situation:

Not authenticated user is typing a comment at some page and presses a submit comment button. POST request with the comment goes to the authorization module which says that authentication is needed. Such authentication is done by for example OAuth on the other page. When OAuth sends back an access token the post request has to be retried with the data sent previously to post a comment. And my question is:

Is there a standard way for retrying post request with the same data? Where to keep such data (which can be also a binary file or something other than just plain text)?

I'm using Spring MVC and Spring Security for user management handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put the content of the post request into a session variable or a cookie and then retrieve the data once the authentication is through.

as soon as the auth starts, the current post will be lost...